# How do you pronounce ACoA?

Tags: pronunciation, acronyms, psychology

How should I pronounce ACoA - the acronym standing for Adult Children of Alcoholics?

Answer (score 1):

When you say an acronym you should spell out each letter individually.

The only exception to that is when the acronym is well-known enough that there can be no confusion, for example NATO, FIFA or CERN, or when there is an accepted pronunciation (such as ["Fannie Mae" for FNMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fannie_Mae)) or when the initialism forms an already-accepted word.

Some organizations like to decide on the pronunciation of their acronym, and it may be that ACoA has a preferred pronunciation, in which case you should follow that. But if you see an unfamiliar acronym written out, and have to pronounce it, just say the letters.

Comment: I thought an acronym is when you say a series of capitalisations as if it *was* a word rather than spelling each letter out, in which case it is just a 'capitalisation'? E.g. LASER is an acronym and TNT is not...

Comment: [Acronym can mean both](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/acronym). Usage decides whether an acronym is pronounced as a word, or spelled out. If it's not accepted as a word, spell out the letters.

Comment: Well- every day is a school day :) And by "capitalisation" I did, of course, mean 'initialism'... Doh!

Comment: +1. Would be good if you could add a source who promulgates the "spell it out unless usage dictates otherwise" advice.

Comment: Thank you for your useful mini-lecture on acronyms :) I just wanted to make it clear that ACoA is not an organization though. It is a concept used by psychologists-practitioners.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is **ah-ko-ah**, but clarity of meaning is key here. If there's a standard usage, then I would suggest following it; I also imagine, however, that some people whose parents were alcoholic might resent being "reduced to a label".

Comment: Perhaps I haven't made myself clear, but the standard usage was what I wanted to ask about. English is not my native language and I don't live in an English speaking country. I fully agree that people should not be "reduced to a label" and I haven't made this "label" up. The concept is based on a theory that people brought up to alcohol-addicted parent(s) share certain characteristics and known transnationally. One may agree with it or not. I just needed to know how to pronounce it... I certainly didn't mean to offend anyone nor "reduce to a label". Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Oh, no offence - just an aside.  I'm prone to rambling when it's the end of an overly-hot summer's day. :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to [two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYZKto4SYts) [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIZHLUVuYjo) I found on YouTube, speakers typically enunciate each letter of *A*,*C*,*o*,*A* individually.

I cannot think of any other way of pronouncing it either.

Comment: Link-only answers are [not answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259). Please summarize the material found in those videos directly in the text of your post here.

Comment: Sure! I'll do it. Thank you for providing that information.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer! :) That's what I thought but I wasn't sure since English is not my native tongue and I haven't thought of YouTube myself :) Thanks again.

Comment: @SaraKaley: No problem!